# solve an iteratively defined equation using optimize.root

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to iteratively solve the following (using scipy/numpy of course):

```
(x_n+1)^2 = ((x_n)^2 + x_n+1) + 1
where x_0 = 1 and x_n > 0 for all n
```

and find the first `20` iterations `(x_1, x_2,..., x_20)`

More precisely, at each iteration we have a quadratic equation of the form `X^2 - X - ((x_n)^2 + 1)`. I want to keep finding the positive root for the first `10` iterations. For example when `n = 0` we get,

```
x_1^ - x_1 - 2 = 0
```

We can feed this into a solver such as `scipy.optmize.root` to find `x_1`. Use that value from the solver for the next iteration etc. I don't know how to even start coding this kind of a problem. Any help?

*A bit of math*: The discriminant of the above general quadratic is positive and so we do indeed have real solutions.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use a general root finder like `scipy.optimize.root` when you could just apply the quadratic formula.

Comment: Actually the problem I am trying to solve is more complicated and an explicit formula for the solution is not possible in that case. I wanted to work with this toy case before I attempted the full solution. I will add more details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use a general root finder for this. Just rearrange your equation and use the quadratic formula, treating the previous x as a constant.

```
(x_n+1)^2 = ((x_n)^2 + x_n+1) + 1
```

Rearranging,

```
(x_n+1)^2 - x_n+1 -((x_n)^2 + 1) = 0
```

So we now have the equation in the form of `ax^2 + bx + c`, with

```
a = 1
b = -1
c = -((x_n)^2 + 1))
```

And since we just want the positive roots,

```
x_n+1 = (1 + sqrt(1 + 4((x_n)^2 + 1))) / 2
```

Simplifying,

```
x_n+1 = (1 + sqrt(5 + 4(x_n)^2)) / 2
```

Translating that into Python:

```
from math import sqrt

x = 1
for i in range(11):
    print(i, x)
    x = (1 + sqrt(5 + 4 * x * x))/2
```

**output**

```
0 1
1 2.0
2 2.79128784747792
3 3.5068734338973964
4 4.1807826995593365
5 4.827694996292443
6 5.455465566142811
7 6.068851276822707
8 6.670976893506619
9 7.264017498033193
10 7.849554422666208
```

Comment: I am trying to solve a more general non-linear problem (still quadratic) but has terms of the form x_n+1 * x_n etc. In this case an explicit formula for the solution is not a possibility. The specific problem is too complicated and domain specific for me to ask here. So I asked this toy problem to get an idea of what I should do. :(

Comment: @minibuffer You should have stated that explicitly in your question. But even in your complex system you can still use the principal of treating the previous `x` as a constant.

Comment: Yeah I should have done that. I will add more details in the morning.